# How to create columns based on the order of other columns in data-frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose we have the following df:

```
df

V1    V2   
1    .50
2    .30
3    .27
4    .59
5    .34
6    .23
7    .56
8    .78
9    .23
```

Now I want to create a column V3 such that it corresponds to the mean of the former values.

In short, V3[3]=.40, for example, would be, ( V2[1] + V2[2] / 2 ) = (.5 + .3)/2.

How would I make that operation using dplyr or plain R? How do i use the order inside the data.frame to perform operations?

I'm asking about some mutate function.

I tried this code in plain R but it doesn't look very efficient:

```
df$V3 <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$V3[i] <- mean(df$V2[1:(i-1)])
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% mutate(V3 = lag(cummean(V2)))

  V1   V2        V3
1  1 0.50        NA
2  2 0.30 0.5000000
3  3 0.27 0.4000000
4  4 0.59 0.3566667
5  5 0.34 0.4150000
6  6 0.23 0.4000000
7  7 0.56 0.3716667
8  8 0.78 0.3985714
9  9 0.23 0.4462500
```

Comment: Suppose I just want the mean of the two previous elements? How do I make that?

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte I have followed your question nothing more nothing less. Next time if you want a precise thing it is better for everyone to ask in your question in a precise way. Anyway I think it can be done easily.

Comment: I asked "How do i use the order inside the data.frame to perform operations?" but I need to precise it.

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte indeed the title seems to have nothing to do with the real question which is to my point of view how to create a new column with the means of previous `n` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?:

```
df$V3 <- cumsum(df$V2)/seq_along(df$V2)
```

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte I do not think that works well as a solution. Consider `V3[3]` for example, it is `0.3566667` while is should be `0.4` and so on.